# Comunicação usando Torrents

Tags: bittorrent

Estou programando um pequeno aplicativo, que faz comunicações P2P, similar a um torrent, e me surgiu uma dúvida teórica em relação aos trackers. Os computadores usam os trackers para saber os "pedacinhos" que os outros computadores possuem?, ou os dados sobre eles são enviados por broadcast para todos os outros computadores, para que tomem ciência que o computador já possui o "pedacinho"?.

Comment: Os trackers servem basicamente pra trocar a lista de pares que tem aquele hash. O hash é resultado do conteúdo do torrent. Os pedaços são negociados entre os pares (e seus hashes conferidos individualmente, para evitar corrupção de dados). Broadcast não vem ao caso pra torrents. Aliás, o uso de broadcast em internet é muito limitado, o mais normal é em redes locais. Na internet você simplesmente não tem como sair fazendo broadcast, até por uma questão de "sanidade" da rede (a nao ser que estejamos falando de broadcast genericamente). Não confundir com DHT, que é um serviço de distribuição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, os trackers só dizem o ip/porta e uma flag (1 ou 0) que indica se aquele host é seed ou leech (tem ou não 100% do conteúdo do torrent). Para obter o resto das informações, é necessário conectar em uma das maquinas que o tracker indica e requisitar as demais informações utilizando o protocolo BitTorrent.

Da uma olhada nisso: https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Messages

Mais precisamente na definição dessa mensagem:

> bitfield: len=0001+X id=5 bitfield The bitfield message may only be
>   sent immediately after the handshaking sequence is completed, and
>   before any other messages are sent. It is optional, and need not be
>   sent if a client has no pieces.
>
> The bitfield message is variable length, where X is the length of the
>   bitfield. The payload is a bitfield representing the pieces that have
>   been successfully downloaded. The high bit in the first byte
>   corresponds to piece index 0. Bits that are cleared indicated a
>   missing piece, and set bits indicate a valid and available piece.
>   Spare bits at the end are set to zero.
>
> Some clients (Deluge for example) send bitfield with missing pieces
>   even if it has all data. Then it sends rest of pieces as have
>   messages. They are saying this helps against ISP filtering of
>   BitTorrent protocol. It is called lazy bitfield.
>
> A bitfield of the wrong length is considered an error. Clients should
>   drop the connection if they receive bitfields that are not of the
>   correct size, or if the bitfield has any of the spare bits set.

Acredito que a tua pergunta já foi respondida na primeira frase, mas para complementar a informação, segue uma tradução (meia boca e bem resumida, da definição da mensagem que postei acima):

> Após a negociação da conexão, ambos os peers devem enviar uma tipo
>   especifico de mensagem, antes de qualquer outra, contendo uma sequencia de  bits, que representa a sequencia de pedaços do conteúdo do torrent. Os bits setados com 1, representam as peças que aquele peer possui, e os bits setados com 0, as peças que ele não possui. Caso o peer não possua nenhuma peça, ele não precisa enviar esta mensagem.